# What is correct way to process POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I have done:

routes.rb:

```
post 'api/last_sync_time' => 'api#set_last_sync_time'
```

controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

def set_last_sync_time
    last_sync_time = params["last_sync_time"]
    FileStorage.initFromFilename('sync').setLastSyncTime(last_sync_time)
end
```

test:

```
curl -X POST -d "last_sync_time=1234567" http://localhost:3000/api/last_sync_time
```

All works file, but in the Rails console I get message:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api/set_last_sync_time,
>   application/set_last_sync_time with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html,
>   :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff,
>   :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form,
>   :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw,
>   :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.

How can I fix it and may there is a better way of doing it ?

Comment: You should be returning a response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return a response. As your request format is `application/json` you can return something like the example below or a more informative message as per the request.

`render json: {success: true}`